# Custom Service Discovery

Tags: sockets, security, networking, tcp

I am trying to write a service discovery protocol for my communication framework. I am planning to do the following steps:

**Server Side**

1. Creating a multicast socket
2. Join a group
3. Broadcast(Send multicast message with some heart-beat [UDP Multicast Protocol]. The broadcast data contains server IP and some port which will be used to process client registration requests
4. Open thread to receive TCP packets from Client on that port to accept registrations

**Client Side**

1. Creating Multicast socket
2. Join the same multicast group as server to receive messages
3. Check for relevant broadcast from service
4. Get data from the broadcast packet (Data is server IP and Port)
5. Make a TCP Call to server(IP and port received) in the form of registration request.

Regarding security vulnerability, I can provide certificates in client registration step to protect that, but my **main concern is in service broadcast**.

If I broadcast server IP and port in a heartbeat that is very dangerous to attacks like port flooding etc.(I can provide some security measure but heavy-weight encryption and decryption will make service discovery lag). Is there any alternative design?

Answer (score 2):

> If I broadcast server IP and port in a heartbeat that is very dangerous to attacks like port flooding etc. (I can provide some security measure but heavy-weight encryption and decryption will make service discovery lag). Is there any alternative design?

An alternative design would be to send a broadcast from a client to discover the server. Just like DHCP and other services work: client broadcasts a "discovery" message, so every sever might response with a service "offer". Please find below more info:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

Regarding the "discovery lag" you mention. Having client send the first "discovery" packet should reduce the lag to a minimum, so that is another plus to "reverse" your model.